# XGB regressor feature selection

Tags: python

Sample dataset

```
Feature1   Feature2  Feature3  Target
10            21        23     25
20            23        24     23
30            23        25     45
```

The following code is being used for fitting XG boost on a regression problem and get the important features. The feature selection method is using the F score for giving the importance.

```
clf = xgb.XGBRegressor(n_estimators=100, gamma=1)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

sorted_idx = clf.feature_importances_.argsort()
plt.barh(X_train.columns[sorted_idx], clf.feature_importances_[sorted_idx])
plt.xlabel("Xgboost Feature Importance")
plt.show()
```

However, F score can be calculated for classification problems using precision and recall.

But in a regression problem, I am predicting a variable, then how are the feature importance being calculated ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several types of importance in the Xgboost.The default type is gain if you construct model with scikit-learn like API. When you access Booster object and get the importance with `get_score` method, then default is weight. You can check the type of the importance with `xgb.importance_type`.
The gain type shows the average gain across all splits where feature was used.
The weight shows the number of times the feature is used to split data. This type of feature importance can favourize numerical and high cardinality features. Remember also that there are also `cover, total_gain, total_cover types` of feature importance.